# ETL incremental extract best practise

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

I need some expert opinion on my design for a daily incremental extract here. I am using SQL 2008 R2 and I have a decent size DB, close to 1 million person records with all their attributes and relationships with another person role.

I want to do two things (for now at least)

1. A consumer wants a dump of what changed (new / updates) in a flat file
2. Another consumer only wants new data in a flat file (different format).

Based on these requirements it appears like only one thing is common, both of them want 'what changed today'. So here's my approach:

1. Create a control table with Tablename and LastExtractDateTime as two columns
2. Create a stage table with pretty much every field all the consumers need
3. I have CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate on all the transacational tables.
4. Every day, let's say at 10 PM, populate the stage (a dedicated SSIS package) table with what changed. Stored procedures to extract all new data (based on CreatedDate) and all changed data (based on LastModifiedDate) of all dates greater than the date in the Control.LastExtractDateTime column
5. On successful extraction of stage data, update Control.LastExtractDateTime with current date.
6. Kick off the other SSIS packages based on whether this one succeeded or not (we have a custom scheduler)

Please comment. Thanks.

Comment: You might consider using change tracking to track your changes and then move to the staging table. Change tracking will monitor all the changes whether there is a date modified field or not. We run our process several times during teh day and as it is using teh change tracking tables to get the changes, it has less impact onteh prod tables. Change tracking is desgned to be easy on the prod tables.

Answer (score 0):

We use something similar, except in your design you are using :control table, while we use Extract_Log_table. In which a record is inserted by extract, along with , extract time, total time it took to execute (Start and end time) and row counts. 
The table becomes reference for answering questions like how much time does it take to extract data on one particular day (say month end, year end, sunday , etc.)

Thank you